# Is Christianity Stack exchange an appropriate place to ask about Judaism and Christianity commonalities?

Tags: discussion, scope

If I understand correctly about the answer to my previous question (Daniel's timeline - Hebraic calendar differences), that is amazing.  The leap years of Torahcalendar 13th month additions are merely not in sync with the Rabbinic method.  However, because the lunar cycles are virtually like clockwork, the same pattern of additions remains preserved.  The net effect of this is to shift the Gregorian years of 13th month additions by exactly two years prior for Torahcalendar.  Thanks for the excellent explanation Davidlol.  I just started using Stack Exchange, and I am impressed.

Not to open a new can of worms, but is Christian Stack exchange generally an appropriate place to ask about Judaism and Christianity commonalities?  There are common roots and a great deal of overlap between the two despite unfortunately long standing differences (i.e. The grafted branches - Romans 11).  I also just realized that there is a "Biblical hermeneutics" Stack exchange (though I can't add hermeneutics as a tag).  Would that be a more appropriate forum?  Thanks.

Comment: Related: [Old/New Testament Jewish culture: On or Off topic?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/293/21576) [Should question on Jewish beliefs be closed?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/600/21576) [Are there Christian answers for Jewish / Judaism questions?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3472/21576)

Answer (score 4):

The problem I have with most "what are the differences between X and Y religions?" questions is the problem imposed by Stack Exchange's one-question-one-correct-answer model.  This isn't a discussion forum.  Therefore, to ideally answer such a question an expert in both X and Y religions would need to provide the answer.

Now, we do the best we can, and the talents and understanding of the people on this site regularly amaze me.  However, the more specific the X vs. Y question, the less likely you'll find anyone who can answer it.

Which is a lengthy way of saying, it doesn't matter if your X vs Y question is Christianity vs. Judaism or Catholics vs. Methodists or anyone else vs. anyone else, the nature of the question is, regrettably, limiting.

Therefore, it would make much more sense to split your question into two, and ask those two questions.  You would have a much higher chance of getting both a greater variety of insight and higher quality insight.  Yes, it leaves you to take the answers from both questions and merge them into the comparison you were looking for, but to my mind, that extra work on your part is a small price to pay to acquire higher quality information in the first place.

Therefore, while Christianity.SE will do the best it can, when it can, when answering Christianity vs. Judaism questions, it often is more productive to ask your Christianity questions here and your Judaism questions there.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here, and I have received great answers to my questions.  I agree.

Comment: The question about the discrepancies between the calendars at a Jewish vs a Messianic Christian website was not a truly Jewish question either.  And there is no Stack exchange for "calendrics".  I think I am just surprised at how quickly questions can get excised from here because of the "apparent" non-conformity to the site's rigid rules by a few (subjective) votes.  My apologies though.  I will try to ask questions in better form.  I am very happy with the high quality of the answers here.

Comment: As I understand it, part of the VTC speed comes from its early years where arguments were more common than answers.  Unfortunately, new users tend to see rapid closure as a form of judgment rather than an opportunity for improvement.  As for subjective... Every question is viewed through the lens of [each participating Christian tradition](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6358/does-this-site-have-a-novel-approach-to-christianity/6359#6359)... and they don't all agree.  What appears subjective to you may be believed utterly objective to the voter.

Comment: @curiousdannii- I asked a question about when bar mitzvah was changed from 20 years of age to 13 years of age and it was closed because it wasn't in the right section. Can someone migrate it into the right section for me, perhaps Old/New testament Jewish Culture? I don't know how to do it because I'm new to CSE.

Comment: @Lesley, let me help you with some of that newness.  You can't notify someone via comments who hasn't commented.  In other words, Curiosdannii won't see your comment because he hasn't commented here.  Scoot backover to your question, where I assume Curiosdannii posted a comment or two, and ask for this help there.

Comment: @JBH- Silly me! Thanks for the advice (and for being nice).

Comment: I don't think the answer here or the comments offered here are adequate or helpful.  JBH - my question was certainly not a "what are the differences between X and Y religions?" question.  What is the purpose of the Christianity site or this "Meta" site?  They both appear to be discussion forums for formal, narrowly religious, intellectual, denominational, "Christian"  debate.  At least I can and will appreciate that I received an answer to my original question before it was "debated" as off topic and "migrated" away.

Comment: @user22542, I regret that you've not found value here, but it's worth noting that [Stack Exchange is not a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums/92110#92110) (see also [Help Center: Don't Ask](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)) nor suitable for debate.  Our specific focus was not compatible with the nature of your question.  I'm delighted, too, that an answer was found before the question was migrated, but the fact that anyone here *could* answer the question doesn't justify an expectation that we shouldn't be the way we are.